# Convert QGIS project automatically to website

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I want to export my QGIS project to website with qgis2web plugin with PyQGIS.

Now I am trying in QGIS GUI Python console. I tried this code with ChatGPT but it give some layer export error I guess. Error is **Uncaught ReferenceError: lyr_OSM_0 is not defined** also other layers not defined. I searched other question about this topic but I couldn't find solution for this. Does anyone have any tips or answers about this? Also its not exporting **correct** output location. Located in appdata\Local\Temp\qgis2web

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsApplication
import processing

ROOT_DIR = ("project/folder")
projectDataRoot = ROOT_DIR + "/data/project_data/mapAndPoint.qgz"
projectWebsiteRoot = ROOT_DIR + "/data/website/"

print(projectDataRoot, projectWebsiteRoot)

prefixPath = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.0\bin'
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(prefixPath, True)

QgsProject.instance().read(projectDataRoot)
alg_params = {
    'INPUT': projectDataRoot,
    'OUTPUT': projectWebsiteRoot,
    'MIN_SCALE': 1,
    'MAX_SCALE': 1000000,
    'TILES': 'OpenStreetMap',  
    'LAYERS': [],  #if empty it will take all layers, also tried only one layer name
    'OPEN_LAYERS': True,
    'OUTPUT_HTML': 'index.html',
    'TEMPLATE': 'full_screen'
}

# Run algorithm
processing.run("qgis2web:exportProject", alg_params)
print("finished")
```

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: lyr_OSM_0 is not defined]

Comment: Are you planning to use qgis2web without opening its graphical interface?  Who are you enclosing to automate your export?

Comment: I did not understand second question. I will use for my school project. Yes, I want to use without GUI that converting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to use qgis2web without going through its graphical interface.  The only possible automation is to use qgis2web in a standard way and export the project, then update the webmap data (only the data, not the styles or other things) using a batch file and OGR2OGR to convert your source data to new geojson (make sure to use the same coordinate system).  The code would be this

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.shp
```

See more info in this github discussion:
https://github.com/qgis2web/qgis2web/issues/957

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I used same solution for this. Just updating gpkg file to geojson and update layer data. Its works now.